# Converting string from xml to NSDate and how to translate the date

Tags: xcode, nsdate, xcode4.5, nsdateformatter

This is my data string:

```
<pubDate>Sun, 24 Mar 2013 00:42:13 +0200</pubDate>
```

I want to convert this to "Sun, 24/3/13, 00:42"
and to translate the day name to hebrew.

here is my code so far:

```
   currentPubDate = [self.xmlParser.pubDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSLocale *loacle = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:loacle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentPubDate];
```

What should I do to make it work?  I've read few guides but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your first part

```
NSString *currentPubDate = @"Sun, 24 Mar 2013 00:42:13 +0200";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentPubDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd/M/yy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

For the translation part you have to set locale, but thats not working in my system as well.

Comment: Great answer, tried using it for some help with what I'm doing, do you have any thoughts on how to tweak it?  Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675839/rkvaluetransformers-failed-transformation-of-value-to-nsdate?noredirect=1#comment40162652_25675839